# How can I change the Folder's Directory Page in HTML?

Tags: xhtml, document, html, w3c

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML Document</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="Folder/.">A Directory</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

By default when I open this link in my internet browser it shows a white page with the items in the directory. Can I change the Directory's Page. For example: http://www.aq.com/gamedesignnotes/ see how the URL points to a directory and not a HTML Document but still shows a page.

Answer (score 0):

Most webhosts will show an `index.html` if you navigate to a directory. You could just create a new file inside your directory called `index.html` and put your HTML there.

Then you can go to `http://yoursite.com/directory` and it will show the `index.html` file in that directory (`http://yoursite.com/directory/index.html`).

[Here is a link to learn more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your webserver. Apache HTTPD generates them using [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) which gives you some control over the apearence via directives such as [`IndexHeadInsert`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexheadinsert).

Answer (score -1):

Your question is how to make pretty (seo friendly) urls right? 
How to make http://website.com/something show a specific html page?

This can be done using mod rewrite using .htaccess files.

Here's a stack overflow topic on mod rewrite:

[Semantic URLs for static HTML files with .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836400/clean-urls-for-static-html-files-with-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Here are some tutorials on pretty urls:

http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/